# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql

I have written this query

```
set sql_safe_updates=0;
delete from t1 where id < (select avg(id) from t1);
set sql_safe_updates=1;
```

but it giving an error

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause
```

please resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the same table used in the `delete` in the rest of the query.  One way to solve this is using a `join`:

```
delete t
    from t1 t join
         (select avg(id) as avgid
          from t1
         )
         on id < (select avg(id);
```

This is a limitation in MySQL.  Another way to get around it is to use an additional level of subqueries:

```
delete from t1 where id < (select avgid from (select avg(id) as avgid from t1));
```

The reason this works is because MySQL will materialize the subquery.  The compiler sort of "forgets" that it is querying from the table bing modified, because of the extra level of subqueries.